# Httpwebrequest error 403 when using proxy to access a https site c#

Tags: c#, ssl, https, proxy, httpwebrequest

Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest firstRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://opizo.com/OEdwHe");
firstRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
firstRequest.Method = "GET";
firstRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0";

WebProxy tempProxy = new WebProxy(Proxy+':'+ ProxyPort  /*"127.0.0.1:8888"*/);
tempProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
tempProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

firstRequest.Accept = "text/html";
firstRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
firstRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
firstRequest.Proxy = tempProxy;
firstRequest.Timeout = 20000;
WebResponse firstResponse = firstRequest.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream firstStream = firstResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader firstStreamReader = new StreamReader(firstStream);
string data = firstStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

The link i want to connect is https , but i enter it in http format.
Proxy + ProxyPort in proxy creation, is of a list of proxies.
The error occurs at `WebResponse firstResponse = firstRequest.GetResponse();`
line.
The exception is "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
Sometimes when i use ssl proxy, "The operation has timed out" exception is thrown and Rarely , no exception is thrown but its probability is one in thousand.

UPDATE: I deleted these two lines

```
firstRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
firstRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

and the error 403's probability is changed from 99% to 1%.
now the exception "The operation has timed out" is thrown.

UPDATE 2: The 403 error is back.
I think there is no way to connect to a https site with http proxy in C# and the best way to solve the issue is to use a SOCKS library.